# C# How to create in-memory video chunks

Tags: c#, winforms, video, screenshot

I need to record screen and on event like button click it should save last 60 seconds of recording.

I know how to capture screenshots but I have problems with converting the images to the video. I want to save the final video file and everything else should be in memory operations.

Currently I save captures as JPEG to memory stream and when the event is fired then I convert the images to the video files. But there is tripple conversion: `Bitmap[] -> JPEG[] -> Bitmap[] -> Video`. That seems ineffective.

When I googled I found only how to save video file to file system. For example Accord library have `VideoFileWritter` (example for version 3.8.2 alpha)

```
Bitmap bitmap; //bitmap object with screenshot
List<byte[]> data = new List<byte[]>();

// fill data with JPEG images (called periodically)
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    data.Add(ms.GetBuffer());
}


// create video file (called on demand)
using (VideoFileWriter videoWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
{
    videoWriter.BitRate = videoBitRate;
    videoWriter.FrameRate = Settings.CurrentFramesPerSeconds;
    videoWriter.Width = 1920;
    videoWriter.Height = 1080;
    videoWriter.VideoCodec = VideoCodec.H264;
    videoWriter.VideoOptions["crf"] = "18"; // visually lossless
    videoWriter.VideoOptions["preset"] = "veryfast";
    videoWriter.VideoOptions["tune"] = "zerolatency";
    videoWriter.VideoOptions["x264opts"] = "no-mbtree:sliced-threads:sync-lookahead=0";
            
    videoWriter.Open(Path.Combine(dirName, "output.avi"));
    foreach (var frame in data)
    {
        using (var bmpStream = new MemoryStream(frame))
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(bmpStream))
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(img))
            videoWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bmp);
    }
}
```

How to create video chunks in memory? I guess it should be CPU and memory more efficient than my current solution.

Or is there more efficient way to record last few seconds of screen without file system usage?

I don't want to use file system because only ssd is installed in computer.

Comment: is it WPF application?

Comment: no it's winforms (I added  tag) but i guess the solution should be similar

Comment: You could use the LEADTOOLS multimedia SDK (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). This [tutorial](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/dotnet-console-create-a-video-from-still-images.html) shows how to take disk images and save them to disk video file. However, it should be easy to modify it to work with memory-based images and video, mainly by changing `convertCtrl.TargetFile` to `convertCtrl.TargetStream`. You can try the [free evaluation](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads), which comes with free tech support through email and live chat.